# How to render forms built in Django in ember.js?

Tags: python, django, ember.js, django-forms, tastypie

So Im developing a website using django as backend framework and ember.js as frontend framework.

I know how to send instances from django to ember.js (via tastypie) and show them in website. I know how to create a form from a model in Django and then render it to template(in django templating language). But how to show it in the web built on ember.js? Without reloading page.

I know this question may seem a bit unspecific, but I have no ideas how to do it.

Comment: I would argue that you should not use two templating engines. Keep you back- and frontend separated and rely on the RESTful API to communicate between the two layers.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that you want to spit out a form definition from tastypie in django?

You'd need to come up with a serializer for a ModelForm or Form from django into json, it would need to spit out something like the following json:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {"type": "text", "name": "username"},
    {"type": "password", "name": "password"},
  ]
}
```

And then use some handlebars/ember magic from [the following answer to render the components in ember](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/dynamically-render-polymorphic-component/3184)?

Comment: Well it doesnt have to do anything with tastypie. I tought it may be possible to get generated html (not json) and put it into my template or something like that?